# What are the 2 different used of Must +present perfect forms?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

She must have helped her ailing parents.

Im the above sentence a guess is made about a past action that definitely or possibly happened.Can such structures be also used to express the wish of the speaker as"It was expected on her part to help her ailing parents?

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't.

Unlike when you use "must" with an infinitive, *must have past participle* only delivers its speculation meaning.

If you want to say that helping her parents was something she was supposed to do but didn't, you could say: ***She should have helped her ailing parents.***

Comment: At the margins, I think you're mistaken. In [my answer to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51029/2637) asked years ago on ELU, I cited Ralph Waldo Emerson's use of ***must*** as a past tense verb form in *What he did, he did because he must.* So far as I'm concerned, that means ***must*** as a past tense usage is interchangeable with ***needed to***, which means that *in principle* OP's text can be interpreted as *She needed to have helped them.* Which is equivalent to *She needed to help them*, but *She must help them* would be a *very* unusual past tense utterance.

Comment: But *learners* should probably ignore that possibility!

Comment: I do agree that "must + infinitive" may sometimes be equivalent to "needed to + infinitive", regardless of how unusual it is, but can "must have + past participle"? It sounds strange to me as I have never heard anybody using it like that. But maybe it's just me as a non-native speaker.

Comment: Yeah - "must have" + pp for "past obligation" rather than "present assumption about the past" sounds weird to me as well. I still remember agonizing for some time over the Ralph Waldo Emerson quote in my link above. And the form here is even *further* "off the beaten track" - but I think if one is "valid", so must the other one be. It's worth noting the peculiar fact that originally, ***must*** was in fact the *past* form of present tense ***mote***, so perhaps we should expect to find other "oddities" here! I find it interesting, but I wouldn't *recommend* it to others, learners or not!